# Como verificar se já existe no banco de dados e efetuar update

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, estou tentando efetuar um update e verificar se o que estou atualizando já existe, eu consigo verificar se existe, mas tem um problema, como eu estou atualizando um dado, ele sempre vai existir, se eu tirar a função que verifica se existe, o usuário poderá atualizar o registro e acabar deixando 2 dados iguais. Tem alguma maneira correta que permite verificar o dado no banco de dados e atualizar?

**Função para verificar se já existe**

```
    public function existsFunction($name){
        try{
            $command = ("SELECT * FROM function
                                WHERE function_nm = '$name'");
            $num_rows = $this->mysqli->query($command)->num_rows;
            if($num_rows < 1){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }catch(Exception $err){
            echo 'Erro: ', $err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Função para atualizar**

```
    public function editFunction($id, $name, $access, $comment){
        try{
            if($this->existsFunction($name)){
                return "already_exists";
            }else{
                $command = ("UPDATE function
                                SET function_nm = '$name',
                                    access_cd = '$access',
                                    function_ds = '$comment'
                                        WHERE function_id = '$id'");
                $query = $this->mysqli->query($command);
                if(!$query){
                    return "error";
                }else{
                    return "success";
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception $err){
            echo 'Erro: ', $err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A declaração `UPDATE` não insere nada no banco, apenas atualiza um registro já existente, portanto não há a minima possibilidade de acabar ficando com 2 dados iguais. Quem coloca registro no banco é a declaração INSERT. Do jeito que você fez se existir nunca vai ser atualizado. Tem que inverter  `if($this->existsFunction($name)){ UPDATE else return "already_exists"`

Comment: Na verdade, bastaria somente a parte que está dentro do else da função atualizar (o UPDATE) sem necessidade das funções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é: Na condição de existência, verificar se existe **e se** é diferente do Id que está sendo atualizado, por exemplo:

```
public function existsFunction($name,$id){
    try{
        $command = ("SELECT * FROM function
                            WHERE function_nm = '$name' AND function_id <> '$id'");
        $num_rows = $this->mysqli->query($command)->num_rows;
        if($num_rows < 1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception $err){
        echo 'Erro: ', $err->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Desta forma, quando for verificar a existência, passe o id como parâmetro também:

```
public function editFunction($id, $name, $access, $comment){
        try{
            if($this->existsFunction($name,$id)){
                return "already_exists";
            }else{
                $command = ("UPDATE function
                                SET function_nm = '$name',
                                    access_cd = '$access',
                                    function_ds = '$comment'
                                        WHERE function_id = '$id'");
                $query = $this->mysqli->query($command);
                if(!$query){
                    return "error";
                }else{
                    return "success";
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception $err){
            echo 'Erro: ', $err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfeito! Está funcionando corretamente da mesma forma que eu queria que estivesse. A única coisa que alterei foi o parâmetro da função, deixei o $id = NULL e na função verificando se recebeu a variável ou não. 
Obrigado pela resposta!